# Hujikar Weapon drop

Tags: blade-and-soul

Do I HAVE to use keys on the chests to get any sort of weapon from this world boss? I ask this because in other boss fights (dungeon and otherwise), there used to be a sealed weapon as a drop plus other extras. Hujikar seems to drop just one chest with a weapon chest inside it. The Hujikar weapon is breakthrough material and is required for me to level up the weapon.
Follow up question if yes: Is using the survey brilliant key for this a good option? Or is there another RNG chest like this further in the game for which I need to hold on the key for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my experiences and reading up on this boss, he does indeed drop a sealed and locked chest and you need to spend the keys to unlock and get your class weapon. Using the level 40 survey moonwater brilliant key is not advised for this particular chest because:

1. Hujikar spawns every 2 minutes and its relatively easy to kill him and obtain a large number of weapon chests.
2. Even though getting a class weapon by using normal keys is based on RNG, this is still advisable since there will be a more demanding dungeon with lower drop-rate of a class weapon further in your weapon upgrade path.

Comment: But you have to take into account the amount of keys and unsealing charms spent, so it's really a preference decision of when to use the moonwater key

Comment: This is still applicable to the keys you spend on the longer dungeons that you have to grind in order to breakthrough later. So, considering just the time needed to get your class breakthrough weapon, you would do better to save the brilliant key to unlock chests obtained from dungeons that need longer time to clear, compared to the box dropped by Hujikar (which has faster spawn rate, is open-world boss and is relatively easy to kill / solo).